# How to fill Combo box from JAVADB

Tags: java, netbeans-6.9

I am using Java Netbeans 6.9.1. I have an Table Called Workers in JavaDB. I want to Display Names of Workers in to Combo box. I am using Combobox on JinternalFrame.

Thanks in advance..

```
try{
String host="jdbc:derby://localhost:1527/Employees";
String uName="admin";
String uPass="admin";
con=DriverManager.getConnection(host, uName, uPass);
stmt = con.createStatement( ResultSet.TYPE_SCROLL_INSENSITIVE, ResultSet.CONCUR_UPDATABLE );
String sql= "SELECT FIRST_NAME FROM APP.Workers";
rs=stmt.executeQuery(sql);
 while (rs.next()) {
String s = rs.getString("FIRST_NAME");
jComboBox1.addItem(s.trim());  } }catch (SQLException err) { System.out.println(err.getMessage() );}      `
```

Comment: Please show us your source code

Comment: What have you tried?  What problems are you having?  Have you tried googling around for making a ComboBox model that interacts with a database?  (And on a minor, very picky, note 'JAVA' should be 'Java')

Comment: @Corbin:- Sorry I have Updatetd

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can populate a swing's JComboBox using `setModel()` method. This outlines what you should have:

```
String[] list = new String[10]; // for example
int count = 0;
while (rs.next()) {
    list[count] = rs.getString("FIRST_NAME");
    count++;
}
jComboBox1.setModel(new javax.swing.DefaultComboBoxModel(list));
```

`setModel()` has one parameter which is a `DefaultListComboBoxModel` object, and this object is initialized using an array of strings as a list of models.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried looking at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1291704/how-do-i-populate-jcombobox-with-arraylist) previous SO post and [this](http://www.java-forums.org/database/15106-populate-jcombobox-database-data.html) other forum post?