# Null Pointer Exception when setting JComboBox

Tags: java, swing, nullpointerexception, null, jcombobox

I am trying to set the value of the combo box to a string that I have found from a text file.  The value is the fifth element in a line in a tab-separated file.

It works correctly when writing to a text field, but I get a null exception error when I try to set the item in a combo box.  Looking on here I believe it is because the value of the lineAsArray[4].toString is null, but I don't understand why it works for the text field but not the combo box.

The issue is in the updateFields method.

Any thoughts all help will be greatly appreciated.

```
import java.awt.EventQueue;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JTextField;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Iterator;

import javax.swing.DefaultComboBoxModel;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.BufferedWriter;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.FileWriter;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.util.LinkedList;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
import javax.swing.JComboBox;
import javax.swing.JPasswordField;
import java.awt.event.ItemListener;
import java.awt.event.ItemEvent;

public class editUser {

    private JFrame frmEditUser;
    private JTextField passwordFld;
    private JPasswordField securePasswordFld;
    private JTextField userNameFld;
    public JComboBox IDcomboBox;
    private JComboBox<String> roleCombo;
    public boolean fieldsBlank;
    public String selectedID;
    public String role;
    private LinkedList<String> UserIDList = new LinkedList<>();
    private JTextField tempFld;
    

    /**
     * Launch the application.
     */
    public static void editWindow() {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                try {
                    editUser window = new editUser();
                    window.frmEditUser.setVisible(true);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });
    }

    /**
     * Create the application.
     */
    public editUser() {
        initialize();
    }

    /**
     * Initialize the contents of the frame.
     */
private void fieldsBlank() {
        
        System.out.println("test");
        System.out.println(userNameFld.getText());
        System.out.println(passwordFld.getText());
        System.out.println(securePasswordFld.getText());
        
                if(userNameFld.getText().equals("")) {
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Please enter a username before submitting","Error Message",2);
                    fieldsBlank=true;
                
                if(passwordFld.getText().equals("")) {
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Please enter a password before submitting","Error Message",2);
                    fieldsBlank=true;
                
                if(securePasswordFld.getText().equals("")){
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Please enter a secure password before submitting","Error Message",2);
                    fieldsBlank=true;
                }
                    }
                        }
        }

private void dataSet() {
    

    System.out.println("dataset method started");
    
    String[] lineAsArray = null;
    String line;
//  String[] userIDArray = null; 
     
    //userDetails myEntry = new userDetails("name","uniformNumber","email","parentContactInfo","d");
    LinkedList<userDetails> myList= new LinkedList<userDetails>();
    

    //myList.add(new userDetails("a","b","c","d","e"));
    
    File fileObj = new File("./Text_Files/" + "users.txt");
    FileReader fr;
    
    try {
        fr = new FileReader(fileObj);
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(fr);
        
    
        while((line = br.readLine())!=null){
            
            {
                lineAsArray = line.split("\t");
                myList.add(new userDetails(lineAsArray[0],
                        lineAsArray[1],
                        lineAsArray[2],
                        lineAsArray[3],
                        lineAsArray[4]));
                
            }
        }
                
        
        
    } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
    }
    

    
    Iterator<userDetails> myIterObj = myList.iterator();
     
     while(myIterObj.hasNext()) {
            System.out.println("iterating through userDetails object");
            userDetails entryObj = myIterObj.next();
            
            System.out.println(userDetails.getID());
            System.out.println(userDetails.getUsername());
            System.out.println(userDetails.getPassword());
            System.out.println(userDetails.getSecurePassword());
            System.out.println(userDetails.getRole());
            
            System.out.println("iteration finished");
            
        
        }

}

     


private void populateCombo() {
    UserIDList.clear();
    String[] lineAsArray = null;
    String line;
    File fileObj = new File("./Text_Files/" + "users.txt");
    FileReader fr;
    int count = 0;
    int counter2 = 0;

    try {
        fr = new FileReader(fileObj);
          BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(fr);
         
          try {
              
            while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
                     lineAsArray = line.split("\t"); //Split the word using tab and add to an array
                                 
                     
                     if(count!=0) {
                     for(int i = 0;i<lineAsArray.length; i++) {
                         System.out.println("current element is: " + lineAsArray[i]);
                        
                        counter2++;
                        
                        if(counter2%5==0) {
                    //   LinkedList<String> UserIDList = new LinkedList<>();

                            // Add elements to LinkedList
                           UserIDList.add(lineAsArray[0]);
                           System.out.println("UserIDs"+ UserIDList);
                        }
                             
                             
                         }
                     
                     }
                     count++;
                 }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    
    }
    
    
    
    
     catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
    
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
          
          }
    

private void updateFields() {
    
    UserIDList.clear();
    String[] lineAsArray = null;
    String line;
    //role = roleCombo.getSelectedItem().toString();
    File fileObj = new File("./Text_Files/" + "users.txt");
    FileReader fr;
    int count = 0;
    int counter2 = 0;

    //selectedID = IDcomboBox.getSelectedItem().toString();
    
    System.out.println(">>>>>>>>>>" +  selectedID);
    try {
        fr = new FileReader(fileObj);
          BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(fr);
         
          try {
              
            while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
                     lineAsArray = line.split("\t"); //Split the word using tab and add to an array
                                 
                     
                     if(count!=0) {
                     for(int i = 0;i<lineAsArray.length; i++) {
                        // System.out.println("current element is: " + lineAsArray[i]);
                        
                        counter2++;
                        
                        if(counter2%5==0) {
                    //   LinkedList<String> UserIDList = new LinkedList<>();

                            // Add elements to LinkedList
                           UserIDList.add(lineAsArray[0]);
                        //   System.out.println("UserIDs"+ UserIDList);
                        }
                        if(lineAsArray[0].toString().equals(selectedID)) {
                            System.out.println("test2");
                            userNameFld.setText(lineAsArray[1].toString());
                            passwordFld.setText(lineAsArray[2].toString());
                            securePasswordFld.setText(lineAsArray[3].toString());
                            
                            System.out.println("Value of lineAsArray[4] " + lineAsArray[4].toString());
                            roleCombo.setSelectedItem(lineAsArray[4].toString());
                        }
                             
                         }
                     
                     }
                     count++;
                 }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    
    }
    
    
    
    
     catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
    
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
          
          }
    


private void initialize() {
    
    populateCombo();
    
    File fileObj = new File("./Text_Files/" + "users.txt");
    
    if (fileObj.exists()) {
        dataSet();
    }
    
        frmEditUser = new JFrame();
        frmEditUser.setResizable(false);
        frmEditUser.setTitle("Edit User");
        frmEditUser.setBounds(100, 100, 450, 300);
        frmEditUser.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frmEditUser.getContentPane().setLayout(null);

        JComboBox<String> roleCombo = new JComboBox<String>();
        roleCombo.setBounds(143, 148, 130, 27);
        frmEditUser.getContentPane().add(roleCombo);
        roleCombo.addItem("Admin");
        roleCombo.addItem("Employee");

        passwordFld = new JTextField();
        passwordFld.setBounds(143, 79, 130, 26);
        frmEditUser.getContentPane().add(passwordFld);
        passwordFld.setColumns(10);
        
        String[] usersArray = {"John","Tracey","Margaret","Betty"};
        
    
        
        
        

        JButton cancelBtn = new JButton("Cancel");
        cancelBtn.setToolTipText("Click this button will cancel all changes");
        cancelBtn.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

                frmEditUser.dispose();
                
                Dashboard dashObj = new Dashboard();
                Dashboard.DashboardWindow();

            }
        });
        cancelBtn.setBounds(14, 237, 117, 29);
        frmEditUser.getContentPane().add(cancelBtn);

        JButton editUserBtn = new JButton("Edit User");
        editUserBtn.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

                fieldsBlank();
                
                if(fieldsBlank==true) {
                System.out.println("Fields left blank, won't continue");
                        
                }
                else {
                
                try {
                    File fileObj = new File("./Text_Files/" + "users.txt");
                    
                    if (!fileObj.exists()) {
                        fileObj.createNewFile();
                        FileWriter fwObj = new FileWriter(fileObj, true);
                        BufferedWriter bwObj = new BufferedWriter(fwObj);
                        bwObj.write("Username");
                        bwObj.write("\t");
                        bwObj.write("Password");
                        bwObj.write("\t");
                        bwObj.write("Secure Password");
                        bwObj.write("\t");
                        bwObj.write("Role");
                        bwObj.close();
                        fwObj.close();

                    }
                    
                    //String username = userNameFld.getText();
                    //String password = passwordFld.getText();
                    //String securePassword = securePasswordFld.getText().toString();
                    //String role = (String) roleCombo.getSelectedItem();
                    

                //  users.setUsername(usernameCombo.getSelectedItem().toString());
                    users.setPassword(passwordFld.getText());
                    users.setSecurePassword(securePasswordFld.getText().toString());
                    users.setRole(roleCombo.getSelectedItem().toString());
                    
                    
                    users usersObj = new users(users.getUsername(), 
                            users.getPassword(), 
                            users.getSecurePassword(),
                            users.getRole());
                    
                    LinkedList<users> list = new LinkedList<users>();
                    list.add(new users(users.getUsername(), users.getPassword(), users.getSecurePassword(),
                            users.getRole()));

                    FileWriter fwObj = new FileWriter(fileObj, true);
                    BufferedWriter bwObj = new BufferedWriter(fwObj);
                    
                    Iterator<users> myIter = list.iterator();
                    while(myIter.hasNext()){
                        users entry = myIter.next();
                        
                        bwObj.newLine();
                        bwObj.write(users.getUsername());
                        bwObj.write("\t");
                        bwObj.write(users.getPassword());
                        bwObj.write("\t");
                        bwObj.write(users.getSecurePassword());
                        bwObj.write("\t");
                        bwObj.write(users.getRole());
                        bwObj.write("\t");
                        
                        
                        bwObj.close();
                        fwObj.close();
                        
                        System.out.println(users.getUsername());
                        System.out.println(users.getPassword());
                        System.out.println(users.getSecurePassword());
                        System.out.println(users.getRole());
                        
                    }

                    
                } catch (IOException e1) {
                    System.out.println("Error Writing to a File");

                }
                }
            }
        });
        editUserBtn.setBounds(314, 237, 130, 29);
        frmEditUser.getContentPane().add(editUserBtn);

        JLabel usernameLbl = new JLabel("Username");
        usernameLbl.setBounds(16, 46, 96, 16);
        frmEditUser.getContentPane().add(usernameLbl);

        JLabel PasswordLbl = new JLabel("Password");
        PasswordLbl.setBounds(16, 84, 96, 16);
        frmEditUser.getContentPane().add(PasswordLbl);

        JLabel roleLbl = new JLabel("Role");
        roleLbl.setBounds(16, 156, 61, 16);
        frmEditUser.getContentPane().add(roleLbl);

        JLabel passwordLbl = new JLabel("Secure Password");
        passwordLbl.setBounds(16, 120, 115, 16);
        frmEditUser.getContentPane().add(passwordLbl);

        securePasswordFld = new JPasswordField();
        securePasswordFld.setBounds(143, 115, 130, 26);
        frmEditUser.getContentPane().add(securePasswordFld);
        
        userNameFld = new JTextField();
        userNameFld.setColumns(10);
        userNameFld.setBounds(143, 41, 130, 26);
        frmEditUser.getContentPane().add(userNameFld);
        
        JLabel bl = new JLabel("ID");
        bl.setBounds(14, 17, 61, 16);
        frmEditUser.getContentPane().add(bl);
        
        JComboBox<String> IDcomboBox = new JComboBox();
        IDcomboBox.addItemListener(new ItemListener() {
            public void itemStateChanged(ItemEvent e) {
                
        
                selectedID = (String) IDcomboBox.getSelectedItem();
                System.out.println("test one" + selectedID);
                
                System.out.println("There was a change in item selection");
                updateFields();
            }
        });
        IDcomboBox.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                
                
            }
        });
        IDcomboBox.setBounds(143, 13, 130, 27);
        frmEditUser.getContentPane().add(IDcomboBox);
        
        //https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1291704/how-do-i-populate-a-jcombobox-with-an-arraylist/29461313
        
        IDcomboBox.setModel(new DefaultComboBoxModel<String>(UserIDList.toArray(new String[0])));
    
        
        
        JButton deleteAll = new JButton("Delete All Users");
        deleteAll.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                
                //https://www.w3schools.com/java/java_files_delete.asp
                
                File fileObj = new File("./Text_Files/" + "users.txt");
                
                fileObj.delete();
            }
        });
        deleteAll.setBounds(314, 208, 130, 29);
        frmEditUser.getContentPane().add(deleteAll);
        
        JButton btnNewButton = new JButton("New button");
        btnNewButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                populateCombo();
            }
        });
        btnNewButton.setBounds(301, 71, 117, 29);
        frmEditUser.getContentPane().add(btnNewButton);
        
        tempFld = new JTextField();
        tempFld.setBounds(153, 187, 130, 26);
        frmEditUser.getContentPane().add(tempFld);
        tempFld.setColumns(10);
        
    

    }
}
```

Comment: In simplifying the code I solved the problem.  I had instantiated the combo box but hadn't created a new one.

`public JComboBox roleCombo = new JComboBox();`

Comment: I assume this meant that I could modify it in the initialization method, but not any other method.

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Added an answer, not sure if I have articulated quite right because I am relatively new to programming.

A big thank you to you and all on StackOverflow it really helps.

Answer (score 0):

Found the solution.

I had to create Combobox where other variables are declared so that both the initializing() method and updateFields() method could access it.

```
public JComboBox roleCombo = new JComboBox();
```